# Need help in opencv sequences !

Tags: c, opencv

I'm using `opencv` sequences to store points resulted from `cvhoughline2`.
I create the sequence and make some operations on it, but when I run the program it breaks in the line `cvseqremove(seq,index)` and gives me the exception:

> > exception at memory location

When I put the cursor on the seq in `cvseqremove(seq,index)`, it writes to me: `h_prev=0*000000000000000`.

I wrote that code, i'll appreciate any help

```c
void APPROXIMATE_LINES(IplImage* image,unsigned int xsize,unsigned int ysize,double width)
{
    unsigned int i;
    IplImage* color_dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8,3);
    IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8,1);
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvSeq* Filtered_Lines=0;
    boolean isbreak;
    double distance=4.0;
    CvPoint Mid_Point;
    CvPoint First_Mid_Point;
    CvSeq* lines = cvCreateSeq(CV_SEQ_ELTYPE_POINT,sizeof(CvSeq),sizeof(CvPoint),storage);
    cvCanny(image,dst,180,250,3);
    cvCvtColor(dst,color_dst,CV_GRAY2BGR);

    lines = cvHoughLines2(dst, storage, CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC, 4, CV_PI/165, 95, 93, 75);
    while (lines->total>1)
    {
        CvPoint* First_Line = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(lines,0);
        First_Mid_Point=mid(First_Line[0],First_Line[1]);
        isbreak=FALSE;

        for( i =1; i < lines->total; i++ )
        {
            CvPoint* line = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(lines,i);
            Mid_Point=mid(line[0],line[1]);
            if(dist(First_Mid_Point.x,First_Mid_Point.y,Mid_Point.x,Mid_Point.y)<distance)
            {
                cvSeqRemove(lines,i);
                isbreak=TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }       /*End_for*/

        if(!isbreak)
        {
            cvSeqPushFront(Filtered_Lines,First_Line); // <--- breaks here
            cvSeqRemove(lines,0);
        }
    } /*End_while*/


    for(i=0;i<Filterd_Lines;i++)
    {
        CvPoint* Filtered = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(Filterd_Lines,i);
        cvLine(color_dst, Filtered[0], Filtered[1], cvScalar(0,0,255,0),1,8,0);
    }

    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage( "Example1",color_dst);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &color_dst);
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
}
```

Comment: You get more views if you learn to tag your question better. I just added the C tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature is:

```
void cvSeqRemove(CvSeq* seq, int index)
```

But on one part of the code you are doing:

```
cvSeqRemove(lines,&i);
```

Which means you are passing the memory address of the variable `i` instead of it's value, and this is not what you want to do.

There might be other bugs.

Comment: @ Karlphillip, i removed the ampersand(&) from the linecvSeqRemove and it run, but now it breaks at the line cvSeqPushFront(Filtered_Lines,First_Line); labeled by --->

Comment: @Eslam There's not much I can do from now on since the code is incomplete and can't be executed. Keep in mind that the function may break if those pointers are not valid (i.e. equal to NULL). So, check if the parameters are good before calling the function on them. Good luck.